# Visualisation strategies for weight matrices in convolutional neural networks

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, matplotlib

What are some common strategies to visualise a weight matrix in a convolutional neural network?

I.e. visualise a matrix with the form (kH, inD, outD) in 1D convolution, and (kH, kW, inD, outD) in 2D convolution, where k is the kernel sizes and in/out is the input/output dimensions.

Preferably in Numpy/Matplotlib

Thanks
Fred

Comment: As currently written, this question appears to be entirely about programming in Python and not about statistics, making it [off-topic here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However you may be able to edit the question to make it on-topic by making it less about syntax in a particular language/package and more generally about data visualization strategies for your particular problem (which ideally you'd describe in a bit more detail).